# Unable to resolve flow annotation error when using immutablejs records and calling update on one

Tags: flowtype, immutable.js

I see the following record type code:

```
type AppProps = {
  +fetches: Map<string, number>,
};
export const makeApp: RecordFactory<AppProps> = Immutable.Record({
  fetches: Immutable.Map()
});
export type App = RecordOf<AppProps>;
```

Now I have a call that uses the record's update function:

```
const state = makeApp({});
const result = state.update('fetches', val =>
    val.set(action.meta.actionBase, 1)
  );
```

All unit tests pass, behaviour is good, but I get a flow error:

> Error:(40, 18) Missing type annotation for `T`. `T` is a type
>   parameter declared in `RecordInstance` [1] and was implicitly
>   instantiated at call of method `update` [2].

I have an idea what is going on here, but I don't know flow well known to actually fix this, or even come up with a workaround. Please help!

ImmutableJS version     "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",

Comment: Have you made any progress with this issue? I am getting a similar issue with Maps and SetIn (Missing type annotation for K. K is a type parameter declared in Immutable.Map [1] and was implicitly instantiated at
call of method setIn [2].) I can't figure out how to resolve it. It appears to be related to a fix that landed in 0.85: https://medium.com/flow-type/asking-for-required-annotations-64d4f9c1edf8

Comment: any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Flow is asking for a concrete type argument for `T`, which is defined in the `update` function of `state`.

Here's another example of a cause and fix of this error message:
[Missing annotation error](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzDigxACUREAeAFQD4AKASgC54BvMZGOVDV1ZBAjwAPvGoBfANwAoGQDdY8AB7wAvASIlyiJrJkBbHMEEgAdCGUAHHDAwBndSqnwA9K-gBZLPftZUAObwUKioOBjEuPgg3LZAA)
[Fixed](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzDigxACUREAeAFQD4AKASgC54BvMZGOVDV1ZBAjwAPvGoBfANwAoGQDdY8AB7wAvASIlyVAM4YYWVAHMGjWTIC2OYIJAA6EMoAOOGBl3qVU+AHpf8ABiWMogwACEQA)

If you provide the type signature of `state.update`, I may be able to provide more information.